# Deliver/Make Delivery

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about informalness of the phrase "*make a delivery*" compared to the verb "*deliver*":

> 1. The delivery man ***delivered ten times***.
> 2. The delivery man ***made ten deliveries***.

Could it be that sentence 2 is informal compared to sentence 1?

Comment: I don't think there is any difference in formality.  Sentence #1 sounds wrong to me, probably because "delivered", in this sense, usually takes an object.    "The delivery man delivered the package" sounds good, but "The delivery man delivered ten times" makes me want to say, "He delivered *what*, though?"

Answer (score 1):

Both phrases could be considered equivalent, but

> **delivered ten times**

usually means the *one thing* was delivered 10 times

> The postman delivered the letter ten times before it was signed for.

whereas

> **made ten deliveries**

usually means that 10 different things were delivered once

> On Monday, FedEx made ten deliveries to the same address.